# How do I add numbers to the end of a copied cell in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here is the situation. I have column B with information, specifically a SKU. I'm making another column next to it containing matrix SKUs, so I want to copy the information from the cell but add a few characters behind it in another cell.

Example

```
**B**               
MIX-MNB
MIX-MNB
MIX-MNB
MIX-MNB

**C**
MIX-MNB-0
MIX-MNB-6
MIX-MNB-12
MIX-MNB-18
```

So i have column B and I want to make it look like column C.

Sorry for the formatting, this is my first post.

Thanks guys

Comment: Where are the suffixes coming from?  Would they be stored in another column?

Comment: No they aren't, because the numbers would always change based on the specific description in the column. i.e., it won't always have 4 MIX-MNB rows in a row, and MIX-MNB might have a -0, -3,-6,-12,-18, or -24 at the end of it. It just depends on the stock of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CONCATENATE function in column C:

```
=CONCATENATE(B1,"-0")
```

You could also use the & (ampersand) operator:

```
=B1&"-0"
```

You could always replace the suffixe with data from another cell:

```
=B1&A1
```